# VBA Outlook - Some MailItems produce runtime error 430

Tags: vba, outlook

I am currently working on a simple VBA macro wich collects some metadata (e.g. `EntryId`, `ReceivedTime`, `Recipients` etc...) of mails in an Outlook mailbox.
To accomplish this it iterates through all folders recursively and collects the data from `MailItems` in every folder.

But I'm getting errors, which are not restricted to the same object (sometimes the error pops up earlier, but never later), stating the object does not support automation (runtime error `430`).

The strange thing is, that roughly 14000 `MailItems` are processed without failure and usually at number 14232 it crashes.

I have two questions regarding this error:

1. I am working on a non local mailbox, therefore only a part of the data should be cached in the local `.ost` file.
   Could data missing in the cache be the cause for the error?
2. And if the cache is not the problem, then what is wrong with my code?

A simplified version of the code:
(Please note that all non `MailItem` objects are ruled out via an explicit typecheck)

```
Sub cache()
    Dim objOl As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim vFolders As Outlook.Folders

    Set objOl = New Outlook.Application
    Set objNs = objOl.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set vFolders = objNs.Folders

    'This is where we're looking for the mailbox to work with
    For i = 1 to vFolders.count
        If StrComp(vFolders(i), "The Mailbox") = 0 Then
            walk vFolders(i)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub walk(folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder)
    Dim item As Object
    Dim vItems As Outlook.Items
    Set vItems = folder.Items

    If vItems.count > 0 Then
        For i = 1 to vItems.Count
            Set item = vItems(i)
            If item.class = 43 Then
                'This is where the debugger shows the runtime error 430
                Debug.Print item.EntryID & vbCrLf & item.ReceivedTime
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Dim vFolders as Outlook.Folders
    Set vFolders = folder.Folders 
    If (vFolders.count > 0) Then
        For i = 1 To vFolders.Count
            walk vFolders(i)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

I updated the code according to the suggestions. No multi-dot notation and no `For Each` loops, the performance increased but the problem keeps occuring at the exact same item, as soon as I try to access data like (subject, entryID or else).

Comment: Seems like you are running out of memory in VBA. If you post the complete code, we can see what you do with the items and suggest ways of improving memory use. Or does the above code also produce the problem?

Comment: The only thing I'm doing is printing the data to a file like this: `print #1, item.EntryID`. Nothing else...

Comment: ..or running out of stack space in your recursion. Try `Sub walk(folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, ByVal depth As Integer)` and call with `walk tmpFolder, depth + 1` to track your recursion depth.

Comment: I did what you asked and the deepest recursion level until the crash is at 5, and it doesn't even crash there, it crashes at 3. Therefore I assume this can be ruled out.

Answer (score 1):

Since your error is happening in the same mailitem every time, I would validate what item 14232 is.  From my experience just because it validates as enum 43 (or olMail) doesn't mean that all of the data will be valid.  Is there anything special about 14232?

**Edit**:
I am currently working on a project using vb and outlook mailitems.  I just identified the Item.MessageClass property defines the sub mailitem type.  When I attempt to cast a message with a MessageClass other than IPM.Note it will give me a 430 error.  Some of the MessageClass values that have given me problems include IPM.Note.Rues.ReplyTemplate.Microsoft and IPM.Note.Rules.OofTemplate.Microsoft.  When I break on these messages I can see that most of the item's properties are not available.  I would add an if check on your loop like this:

```
If item.class = 43 then
    If item.messageclass = "IPM.Note" Then
        Debug.Print item.EntryID & vbCrLf & item.ReceivedTime
    End If
End If
```

this will then only print the info for normal messages.  You may want to do some debugging on the MessageClass properties that you are currently able to process and see if they are all IPM.Note or if you can pinpoint the sub-type that is causing your problem.

Note: I do see that these mailitems still have a valid EntryID and ReceivedTime so I am not sure what the problem might be. What line of the code is your error occurring? The assignment of vItems(index) to Item? or is it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, avoid using multiple dot notation. Secondly, try not to use "for each" loops - they keep the collection items referenced until the loop exits. Do not use `MailItem.Close` - it does nothing unless you are actually showing the item in an `Inspector`.

```
dim vItems as Outlook.Items
vItems = folder.Items  
for I = 1 to vItems.Count
  set item = vItems.Item(I)
  if item.Class = 43 Then
    Debug.Print item.EntryID & vbCrLf & item.ReceivedTime
  End If
  set item = Nothing
Next
```

Comment: I just updated the code according to your hints and suggestions, but the error keeps occuring at the same item. To be exact it crashes always at the exact same item.

Comment: Which exact line that it crash on? When you access the Items.Item() function, Class property? EntryID?

Comment: It crashes as soon as I try to access any mail related data (like subject, or received data) or the entryID.

Comment: Hmmm.. I can only suggest switching to MAPIFolder GetTable() - aside from the error, it will make your code run a lot faster.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that out, maybe there is indeed some sort of memory error which could be resolved via this method. Aside from that, could it be that some mail items on the server are corrupt and therefore not readable?

Comment: Tip: never use something like `for I = 1 to vItems.Count` because `vItems.Count` will be evaluated every round of the loop (and sometimes gives errors).

Comment: Yes, most likely OOM cannot handle that item for some reason. Table does not open the items, it simply retrieves properties from multiple items in a single call (think an ADO Recordset object).

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie. Most languages,. even the scripting ones, will evaluate the loop counter once before entering the loop. If the count changes, you can try a down count (for i = vItems.Count to 1 step -1)

Comment: Alright, will keep that in mind, thanks.
It seems that this one mail object is indeed corrupt. I just skipped it and it seems all other items got processed correctly.

Comment: @Dmitry-Streblechenko, C for example evaluates the terminating condition (the counter) at _every_ iteration, which is correct because the terminating condition can change in the loop. All languages do that. What you say is correct though: "...evaluate the loop counter once before entering the loop" because the loop can iterate zero times. But not "once", but every iteration.)

Comment: Not all languages, Delphi will evaluate the counter only once for the "for" loops and on each iteration for the "while" and "repeat" loops. Either way, changing the collection within a loop is not a good idea - imagine you delete an element with the index i, the collection changes, the element that used to be at i+1 will be at i, and your next iteration (i+1) will process what used to be I+2 thus missing one element. Oops...