# Extract Outlook Emails from Subfolder (Shared Inbox) to Excel

Tags: vba, outlook

I have code that pulls directly from a shared folder's inbox.

I need it to pull from the Subfolder.
For example:
Shared Folder X
-Inbox
--Subfolder

Also, I would like to pull only the first two lines of every email and not drag in the entire email chain.

The below code pulls from the shared inbox.

```vb
Sub GetEmails()

'Add Tools->References->"Microsoft Outlook nn.n Object Library"
'nn.n varies as per our Outlook Installation
Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim sFolders As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim iRow As Integer, oRow As Integer
Dim strMailboxName As String
Dim Pst_Folder_Name As String
strMailboxName = "Shared Email Box"

'Mailbox or PST Main Folder Name (As how it is displayed in your Outlook Session)
strMailboxName = "Shared Email Box"

'Mailbox Folder or PST Folder Name (As how it is displayed in your Outlook Session)
Pst_Folder_Name = "Inbox" 'Sample "Inbox" or "Sent Items"

'To directly a Folder at a high level
'Set Folder = Outlook.Session.Folders(MailBoxName).Folders(Pst_Folder_Name)

'To access a main folder or a subfolder (level-1)
For Each Folder In Outlook.Session.Folders(strMailboxName).Folders
    If VBA.UCase(Folder.Name) = VBA.UCase(Pst_Folder_Name) Then GoTo Label_Folder_Found
    For Each sFolders In Folder.Folders
        If VBA.UCase(sFolders.Name) = VBA.UCase(Pst_Folder_Name) Then
            Set Folder = sFolders
            GoTo Label_Folder_Found
        End If
    Next sFolders
Next Folder

Label_Folder_Found:
    If Folder.Name = "" Then
        MsgBox "Invalid Data in Input"
        GoTo End_Lbl1:
    End If

    'Read Through each Mail and export the details to Excel for Email Archival
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
    Folder.Items.Sort "Received"

    'Insert Column Headers
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = "Sender"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2) = "Subject"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 3) = "Date"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 4) = "Body"

    'Export eMail Data from PST Folder to Excel with date and time
    oRow = 1
    For iRow = 1 To Folder.Items.Count
        'If condition to import mails received in last 18 days
        'To import all emails, comment or remove this IF condition
        If VBA.DateValue(VBA.Now) - VBA.DateValue(Folder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime) <= 18 Then
            oRow = oRow + 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 1).Select
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 1) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderName
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 2) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Subject
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 3) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 4) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Body
        End If
    Next iRow

    MsgBox "Outlook Mails Extracted to Excel"
    Set Folder = Nothing
    Set sFolders = Nothing

End_Lbl1:
End Sub
```

Comment: For the first two lines you can split the `Body` on vbCrLf (or maybe on vbLF) and take the first two elements of the resulting array.  Or just take the first (eg) 200 characters using `Left()`

Comment: Im sorry, Im very new to vba. I have no idea what you just said. Would you be able to help me write it out?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Sub GetEmails()

    'Add Tools->References->"Microsoft Outlook nn.n Object Library"
    'nn.n varies as per our Outlook Installation
    Const NUM_DAYS As Long = 18
    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim itm As Object
    Dim iRow As Long, oRow As Long, ws As Worksheet, sBody As String
    Dim mailboxName As String, inboxName As String, subfolderName As String, diff As Double
    
    mailboxName = "mailboxNameHere"
    inboxName = "Inbox"
    subfolderName = "Contracts" 'for example

    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Folder = OutlookApp.Session.Folders(mailboxName) _
                     .Folders(inboxName).Folders(subfolderName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Folder Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Source folder not found!", vbExclamation, _
                "Problem with export"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    ws.Cells.ClearContents
    'add headers
    ws.Range("A1").Resize(1, 4).Value = Array("Sender", "Subject", "Date", "Body")
    iRow = 2
    Folder.Items.Sort "Received"
    For Each itm In Folder.Items
        If TypeOf itm Is Outlook.MailItem Then       'check it's a mail item (not appointment, etc)
            diff = -999                     'reset time difference
            On Error Resume Next            'ignore error if Receivedtime not available
            diff = Date - itm.ReceivedTime  'try to calculate interval
            On Error GoTo 0                 'stop ignoring errors
            If diff <> -999 Then            'could read Receivedtime?
                If diff <= NUM_DAYS Then
                    sBody = Left(Trim(itm.Body), 150)    'first 150 chars of Body
                    sBody = Replace(sBody, vbCrLf, "; ") 'remove newlines
                    sBody = Replace(sBody, vbLf, "; ")
                    ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value = _
                        Array(itm.SenderName, itm.Subject, itm.ReceivedTime, sBody)
                    iRow = iRow + 1
                End If
            Else
                Debug.Print "Couldn't read ReceivedTime" & vbLf & _
                             itm.SenderName & ":" & itm.Subject
            End If
        End If
    Next itm

    MsgBox "Outlook Mails Extracted to Excel"

End Sub
```

Comment: Only thing is, do you know why it hangs so much when i run the code? I had to force quit after waiting for an hour. I got the results from auto-recovery excel

Comment: How many mails in the folder?

Comment: I ran the code for the past 24 days. About 1200 emails maybe

Comment: Well I guess it might take some time to run then?  I'm not able to test that here.  Maybe add a `Debug.Print` within the loop so you can monitor the progress.

Comment: When i am trying to run this code, i get a 430 error and the debug points to this line If Date - itm.ReceivedTime <= NUM_DAYS Then

what does this mean?

Comment: What's the text of the error?  Maybe that item doesn't have a ReceivedTime ?  Does it always error on the same message(s)?

Comment: Initially i didnt get this error - but it points to this line. I tried different length of times, but it only pulls up to 7 days.

Comment: Does it always hang on the same item?

Comment: Maybe look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34532139/478884

Comment: Yes - every single time. The issue is with this line: If Item.ReceivedTime <= NUM_DAYS Then

I tried to changed itm to item.. that doesnt help.


Just would like to add a little more info - This issue only happens when i am trying to extract email subfolders. When i try to pull the actual INBOX, it doesnt happen.

Comment: There's something different about one or more of the items it's hanging on - I added a `Debug.Print itm.MessageClass` line above - see if that gives you some clue about type(s) of messages you should skip.

Comment: Still getting the 430 Error code on ```If Date - itm.ReceivedTime <= NUM_DAYS Then```

Comment: You're ignoring my question about whether it always hangs on the same item(s)... I can't see your inbox so I have to ask questions instead.

Comment: sorry - i thought i answered above. 
Yes - every single time. The issue is with this line: If Item.ReceivedTime <= NUM_DAYS Then I tried to changed itm to item.. that doesnt help. Just would like to add a little more info - This issue only happens when i am trying to extract email subfolders. When i try to pull the actual INBOX, it doesnt happen.

Comment: Sorry I can't reproduce the problem.  Perhaps the best you could do is to skip the items where `ReceivedTime` is not available - see edits above.

Comment: IT WORKED!!!! YOU ARE THE BEST! THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!!! :DDD 
On top of it all, i know you have been helping me with this since the beginning! Thank you very very much! I truly appreciate it!

Comment: Note **it may end up skipping items that you wanted** - you have to check the Immediate pane in the VB editor to see how many got skipped because ReceivedTime was not available...